# Why can't I get the permission for RECORD AUDIO in android studio from fire tv cube device?

Tags: android, amazon-fire-tv

recently I'm developing an android app, so this app will use the audio record feature. My app already ran successfully, but suddenly, my app stopped from 1 week ago.
For this, I'm going to get the RECORD_AUDIO permission, of course, I added this permission code line into the manifest file. But I'm getting -1 value, this means it is denied from the device. Please let me know the solution if you know it already. Thank you very much!
**- About my fire tv cube device.
Device Name: Fire TV Cube
Software Version: Fire OS 7.2.1.2(PS7212/1333)
Fire TV Home Version: 6221059.1**

Comment: It may be that the microphone is not available for app developers and is reserved for use by Alexa.

Comment: Sorry, I mean is not Alexa.

Comment: https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/231815/the-record-audio-permission-has-been-blocked-recen.html

Comment: Looks like it is no longer possible to request this permission since a Fire OS update. There is a workaround using ADB, see: https://community.hueessentials.com/t/how-to-use-dance-sensation-and-disco-on-amazon-fire-tv/499